# not displaying character linked list in c

Tags: c

program is about merging two sorted linked list having character information.Merged list should also be sorted .However my Display function is not printing the character linked list.The function is being called in main but characters are not being printed.

```
struct node
{
    char info;
    struct node *link;
};
typedef struct node *NODE;


void Insert(NODE, char);
void Display(NODE);
NODE getNode();
int main()
{
    int num, i, c1, c2;
    char item;
    NODE head1, head2, head3;
    NODE temp1, temp2;
    head1=getNode();
    head2=getNode();
    head3=getNode();
    printf("First List:\n");
    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf ("%d", &num);
    printf ("Enter the elements in sorted order:\n");
    for (i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &item);
        getchar();

        Insert(head1, item);
    }
    printf("Second List:\n");
    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf ("%d", &num);
    printf ("Enter the elements in sorted order:\n");
    for (i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &item);
        getchar();
        Insert(head2, item);
    }
    temp1=head1->link;
    temp2=head2->link;
    while (temp1!=NULL&&temp2!=NULL)
    {
        c1=(int)temp1->info;
        c2=(int)temp2->info;
        if (c1<c2)
        {
            Insert(head3, temp1->info);
            temp1=temp1->link;
        }
        else
        {
            Insert (head3, temp2->info);
            temp2=temp2->link;
        }
    }
    while (temp1!=NULL)
    {
        Insert(head3, temp1->info);
        temp1=temp1->link;
    }
    while (temp2!=NULL)
    {
        Insert (head3, temp2->info);
        temp2=temp2->link;
    }

    Display(head3);
    return 0;
}

void Insert (NODE head, char item)
{
    NODE temp = getNode();
    NODE p;
    temp->info=item;
    temp->link=NULL;

    if (head->link==NULL)
        head->link=temp;

    else
    {
        p=head->link;
        while(p->link!=NULL)
            p=p->link;
        p->link=temp;
    }
}


void Display(NODE head)
{
    NODE temp;
    temp=head->link;
    if (head->link==NULL)
        printf("The list is empty.\n");
    else
    {
        printf("The joined list is:\n");
        while (temp!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%c \t",temp->info);
            temp=temp->link;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

NODE getNode()
{
    NODE temp;
    temp=(NODE) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->link=NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: In case you ultimately decide the current behavior is *not* what you want, you never consume the newline after your length-input of each list. Therefore the polarity of your input loops is backwards. You're inserting newlines-only from the `scanf` results, and discarding the actual characters you want with the blind `getchar()` invoke.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you? Or what about adding `printf()`'s to see where things go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

put a space before `%c` for your both `scanf(...)`  which reads character

```
scanf(" %c", &item);
```

The problem is that `%c` does not skip white space as do the numerical formats such as `%f` and `%d.`

Comment: ... and lose the `getchar()`